# Python Pandas: Retrieve id of data from a chunk

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The dataset is read chunk by chunk, because it is to big. The ids are the first column and I would like to store them in data structure like array. So far it is not working. It looks like this

```
tf = pd.read_csv('data.csv', chunksize=chunksize)
for chunk in tf:
    here I wanna store the ids chunk["Id"] in an array
```

How do I do that?

Comment: why don't you just read that column? e.g. `tf = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=['Id'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
ids = pd.DataFrame()
tf = pd.read_csv('data.csv', chunksize=chunksize)
for chunk in tf:
    ids = pd.concat([ids, chunk['Id']], ignore_index=True)
```

you can always access `ids` Series as NumPy array:

```
ids.values
```

Comment: But I need the rest of the row as well. So I don't use usecols.

Comment: But it is not relevant for the current problem. I just modified your previous answer as you just did yourself.

Comment: How can I set the column name as Id?

Comment: @tumbler, do you need a DF with one column or a series?